# apply filter to top row excel using office-js

Tags: excel, office-js

I was wondering if it is posible to apply a filter to a range in excel the same way it is posible using the user interface?

aplogies for the dutch excel installation [image]

[image: Filter in excel sheet]

Comment: You can do this as of API 1.9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58702632/3806701

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [filter](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/filter.md) API is available on [table column](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/tablecolumn.md) and allows filtering based on [criteria](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/filtercriteria.md) and on few other scenarios such as color, top %, etc. You can clear the filters as well. It is not available directly on the range object. When range column is introduced, we could extend that for range as well.

Comment: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16415683-add-the-option-to-aply-filters-to-an-excel-range-f