# Excel Office JS filter data

Tags: office-js

In Excel a user can select a range and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to show filters. I am trying to get equivalent behavior from an Office.js Add-in.

The closest I have come to that is adding a table over the range I want to filter and then adding a filter to the table.  There seem to be a couple of significant problems with that however.

First, adding a table this way for 30000+ rows is very slow and I am frequently using tables much larger than that.  If I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> over a range that size it is instantaneous.

Additionally, when I add the table, Office.js stylizes the range. I do not want any new styling for the range I just want a filter added.

My current code looks like this:

```js
await Excel.run(async ctx => {
    const table = await getOrCreateDataTable(ctx, "CostData", new ExcelRange(this.stateService.headerRow)); //see below
    const validationColumn: Excel.TableColumn = table.columns.getItemOrNullObject("Validation");
    validationColumn.filter.applyCustomFilter(`*${searchString}*`)
    await ctx.sync();
});

export const getOrCreateDataTable = async(ctx: Excel.RequestContext, tableName: string, headerRow: ExcelRange): Promise < Excel.Table > => {

    let table: Excel.Table = ctx.workbook.tables.getItemOrNullObject(tableName)
    await ctx.sync();
    if (!table.isNullObject)
        console.log(`Table: ${tableName} found`)
    else {
        const sheet = await getSheet(ctx, headerRow.sheet)
        const headerRange = sheet.getRange(headerRow.getRange()).getEntireRow().getUsedRange()
        const usedRange: Excel.Range = sheet.getUsedRange()
        const tableRange = headerRange.getBoundingRect(usedRange.getLastCell())
        table = ctx.workbook.tables.add(tableRange, true)
        table.name = tableName
        await ctx.sync();

    }
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can now add filters to ranges as of Excel Javascript API 1.9:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-1-9-requirement-set

Here's an example to apply a custom filter which will find cells with the substring "test":

```
Excel.run((ctx) => {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    var range = sheet.getUsedRange();
    var columnIndex = 3; //zero based index
    var condition = { criterion1: "=*test*", filterOn: Excel.FilterOn.custom }        

    sheet.autoFilter.apply(range, columnIndex, condition);

    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(errorHandlerFunction);
```

Remove filters with:

`sheet.autoFilter.remove();`

Find more details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-worksheets#filter-data

Or in script lab: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/

Answer (score 0):

Currently `ExcelApi` only supports filtering on a [Table](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/table) object.

What you're looking for here would be support for filtering a [Range](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range). I would highly recommending visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and this suggestion.

Comment: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/16415683-add-the-option-to-aply-filters-to-an-excel-range-f

Answer (score 0):

Mashing up @cs_pupil answer and MS Docs I came up w/ this function.

Note: The first thing I noticed after getting the MS version to work was that it didn't work correctly w/ Wildcards which is what I use mainly, so I switched to `custom` filtering vs `values`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-tables#apply-filters-to-a-table

```
function Do_FilterTable(TBLObj, ColHeader, criterion1Str) {
    TBLObj.columns.getItem(ColHeader).filter.apply({
        filterOn: Excel.FilterOn.custom,
        criterion1: criterion1Str
    }); 
}
```

Here is some more example code for filtering a range and using 2x `criterion`:

```
var ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var range = ws.getUsedRange();
var columnIndex = 27; //zero based index
var condition = {
    criterion1: ">42",
    operator: "Or",
    criterion2: "=*>*",
    filterOn: Excel.FilterOn.custom
} 
ws.autoFilter.apply(range, columnIndex, condition);
```

And... A Settings Obj I make to help me remember things:

```
const Filter_Settings_Obj = {
    "filterOn": {
        "Excel": {
            "FilterOn": {
                "BottomItems": "BottomItems",
                "BottomPercent": "BottomPercent",
                "CellColor": "CellColor",
                "Dynamic": "Dynamic",
                "FontColor": "FontColor",
                "Values": "Values",
                "TopItems": "TopItems",
                "TopPercent": "TopPercent",
                "Icon": "Icon",
                "Custom": "Custom",
            },
            "DynamicFilterCriteria": {
                "Unknown": "Unknown",
                "AboveAverage": "AboveAverage",
                "AllDatesInPeriodApril": "AllDatesInPeriodApril",
                "AllDatesInPeriodAugust": "AllDatesInPeriodAugust",
                "AllDatesInPeriodDecember": "AllDatesInPeriodDecember",
                "AllDatesInPeriodFebruray": "AllDatesInPeriodFebruray",
                "AllDatesInPeriodJanuary": "AllDatesInPeriodJanuary",
                "AllDatesInPeriodJuly": "AllDatesInPeriodJuly",
                "AllDatesInPeriodJune": "AllDatesInPeriodJune",
                "AllDatesInPeriodMarch": "AllDatesInPeriodMarch",
                "AllDatesInPeriodMay": "AllDatesInPeriodMay",
                "AllDatesInPeriodNovember": "AllDatesInPeriodNovember",
                "AllDatesInPeriodOctober": "AllDatesInPeriodOctober",
                "AllDatesInPeriodQuarter1": "AllDatesInPeriodQuarter1",
                "AllDatesInPeriodQuarter2": "AllDatesInPeriodQuarter2",
                "AllDatesInPeriodQuarter3": "AllDatesInPeriodQuarter3",
                "AllDatesInPeriodQuarter4": "AllDatesInPeriodQuarter4",
                "AllDatesInPeriodSeptember": "AllDatesInPeriodSeptember",
                "BelowAverage": "BelowAverage",
                "LastMonth": "LastMonth",
                "LastQuarter": "LastQuarter",
                "LastWeek": "LastWeek",
                "LastYear": "LastYear",
                "NextMonth": "NextMonth",
                "NextQuarter": "NextQuarter",
                "NextWeek": "NextWeek",
                "NextYear": "NextYear",
                "ThisMonth": "ThisMonth",
                "ThisQuarter": "ThisQuarter",
                "ThisWeek": "ThisWeek",
                "ThisYear": "ThisYear",
                "Today": "Today",
                "Tomorrow": "Tomorrow",
                "YearToDate": "YearToDate",
                "Yesterday": "Yesterday",
            },
        },
    },
    "operator": {
        "And": "And",
        "Or": "Or",
    },
}
```